# Showing that the polynomial $x^n+y^n-1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

I’d like to show that the polynomial $x^n+y^n-1$ ($n \geq 1$) is irreducible over $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ (because I want to see that $x^n+y^n=1$ defines a smooth curve). I’ve been told this can be done by using (a generalization of?) Eisenstein’s criterion for $\mathbb{C}[x][y]$, since $\mathbb{C}[x]$ is an UFD, but I’m not sure how to proceed since I only know how to apply it over the rational numbers. Any help or hints would be welcome.

Comment: Eisenstein's criterion generalizes to any ring $D[x]$, where $D$ is an integral domain. So, as suggested to you previously, consider $x^n + y^n - 1$ as a polynomial in $\mathbb{C}[y][x]$. Can you find a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ of $\mathbb{C}[y]$ such that the constant term of your polynomial is in $\mathfrak{p}$ but not in $\mathfrak{p}^2$?

Comment: @user1090793 The constant term is $y^n-1$, and all prime ideals of $\mathbb{C}[y]$ are of the form $(y-\alpha)$ with $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$, right…?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Write the polynomial as $y^n+(x-1)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+...+x+1)\in\mathbb{C}[x][y]$.

Comment: Should I consider the prime ideal of $\mathbb{C}[x]$ given by $(x-1)$?

Comment: @gisame You can, or just note that $x-1$ is a prime/irreducible element, and use the Eisenstein criterion just like over $\mathbb{Z}$.